# Did the student body know about Barty Crouch Jr?

Tags: harry-potter, barty-crouch-jr

When Barty Crouch, Jr. was apprehended at the end of *Goblet of Fire* it was done by a handful of professors. Harry was there only because Crouch took him.

Much like when  Dumbledore comments at the end of *Philosopher's Stone* referring to the battle between Harry and Quirrel,

> What happened is a secret, so naturally the whole school knows.

Is there any evidence that the same thing took place for this event?

Comment: Was there any reason for the students to know who he even was? The events from the first book involved people from the school, what did BCjr have to do with the school, and why would "the whole school" care?

Comment: @Seeds did you read the books?

Comment: It's been a few years, was there something particular you had in mind?

Comment: @Seeds Just saying. BCjr was very important to the school for Harry's 4th year... bu he was known by a different name...

Comment: Which was kind of my point.

Comment: Dumbledore may have brought it up in passing in his end-of-year speech. Or else, as you say, gossip. I can't imagine that Cedric's death and the circumstances around it would be something that people *wouldn't* have talked about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Most likely, yes

Worth remarking that Dean brings this up to Umbridge in *Order of the Phoenix*:

> "It is my understanding that my predecessor not only performed illegal curses in front of you, he actually performed them on you —"
>
> "Well, he turned out to be a maniac, didn't he?" said Dean Thomas hotly.
>
> <sup>*Order of the Phoenix* Chapter 12: "Professor Umbridge"</sup>

Although he doesn't explicitly say "our last professor turned out to be the crazy, supposed-to-be-dead son of a Ministry employee whose initials are B.C."; it seems rather unlikely that Dean could be referring to anything else.

Comment: As an aside, it occurs to me that the Ministry may be playing up this story in the media; "Dumbledore hires convicted Death Eater as professor; too dumb to tell that old friend is being impersonated by polyjuice" seems like a great addition to their smear campaign

Comment: I remember that, in Order of the Phoenix, Fred or George mentioned something about the former DADA teacher being imprisoned for a full year. But they might know it because they also spent some time in the HQ of the Order.